# How to get a cursor with distinct values only?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor, distinct-values

I want to return a cursor only with distinct values of a column.
The column 'Groups' has more items but with only 2 values: 1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1

```
String[] FROM = {Groups,_ID};

public Cursor getGroups(){
//......
return db.query(TABLE_NAME,FROM,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

will return a cursor containing {1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1} but I would like to contain just {1,2}.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have an sql query like this,

```
public Cursor usingDistinct(String column_name) {
        return db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT "+column_name+" from "+TBL_NAME, null);
    }
```

Comment: The error was because you did call `cursor.moveToFirst();` after `Cursor cursor = getGroups();`

Comment: Now I want to extract values from cursor.I have tried:
  String gr1 = cursor.getString(0);
  String gr2 = cursor.getString(1);` but I get the error: `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2` . Then I have change it to: `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT "+column_name+" from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
  
  if(cursor != null){
   cursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  
  return cursor;` and now, I can access just the first value,getString(0). When I try getString(1) I get NULL. Any idea how can I extract both values from the cursor?Thanks for the solution provided by now.

Comment: I found, I shouldn't call cursor.getString(1) because the cursor has just 1 column with more rows. Instead I should do: `while(cursor.moveToNext()){
   ....cursor.getString(0);
   .......
  }` The cursor has the wright content, all distinct values.

Comment: What if I want the entire row of the distinct column?

Answer (score 5):

you can use distinct argument while making query like this:

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

Follow this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more clearity.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example query, as you have to give column name for distinct

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, YOUR_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_NAME_1 ,COLUMN_NAME_2, COLUMN_NAME_3 }, null, null, COLUMN_NAME_2, null, null, null);
```

COLUMN_NAME_2 - name of the column for distinct.

remember to add GROUP BY column names

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean **true** iin the distinct argument, For example :

```
public Cursor query (**true**, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit);
```